# JQuery Script has stopped by browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textbox

I am trying to implement a simple web app by using JQuery. What I want to do is: sum all numbers which are entered to a textbox until user presses the space button. The user has to press enter after typed a number. The problem is after I press any button inside textbox the script always stops and I don't know how to fix this. Can anyone help me about this?

Here is my code:

```
$('#textbox').keyup(function (event) {
    var typedNumber = 0;
    var sum = 0;
    var textValue = "";

    do {
        if (event.keyCode == 13) {
            textValue = document.getElementById("textbox").value;
            typedNumber = parseInt(textValue);
            sum = sum + typedNumber;
            document.getElementById("textbox").value = "";
        }
   } while (event.keyCode != 32);

   $('#msg-keypress').html(sum);      
});
```

Comment: didn't read that part of the enter key, using .change() now seems inferior so I deleted my answer sorry. **edit:** my deleted tip _"if you are already using jQuery you should **use** jQuery"_ (so don't use getElementById)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just going to to get stuck in the do{} loop.  Instead of that have something like

```
if(event.keyCode == 13){
   do sum stuff
}
if(event.keyCode == 32){
   set a flag so we stop doing sum stuff
}
```

Comment: Why does it stuck ? I can't see any logical or syntax error but it's not working.Makes me crazy.

Comment: You start the loop on the first keyup, and it'll never stop. It just sits there looping, waiting for event.keyCode to equal 32 which it never will if it didn't first time.

Comment: Thanks for help it works but it causes an another problem. After i pressed spacebar once, no more additions are making.